# Serialization between different domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, serialization, data-transfer-objects

I'm new to serialization.I need to send a Serialized object from a one web site to another web site.
i'm using following serialization code in my first web site

```
 private void Serialize()
    {

        Cuser cat = new Cuser();
        cat.UserNO = 1;
        cat.UerName = "chamara";
        cat.Passwod = "123";
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(cat.GetType());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
        ser.Serialize(writer, cat);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
        Response.Redirect("https://site1.com.au");
    }
```

now i need to retrieve(deserialize) these data from site1.com.i have the deserialization code.i need to know how can i transfer this object? and am i using serialization for the correct purpose? hope my explanation is clear enough to understand the issue.

Comment: Please think about what code you want to execute on one server, another server and browser. Than edit the question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

There is some chance that you want to render data in a form on site-1 and automatically post the form to site-2 with client side script.